# Python: Print stuff in dictionary line by line

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have an assignment where If I input a string for example

```
food food games hi food
```

it would print out like this:

```
food: 3
games: 1
hi: 1
```

the code I made right now is

```
def count_word(string1):
    counts = {}
    words = string1.split()

    for word in words:
        if word in  counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1

    return counts

string1 = str(input())
print(count_word(string1))
```

If I input the same string as above it prints out:

```
{'food': 3, 'games': 1, 'hi': 1}
```

how do I make it so it prints out like this:

```
food: 3
games: 1
hi: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work:

```py
d = {'food': 3, 'games': 1, 'hi': 1} # generated by counter function

for word, count in d.items():
    print(f'{word}: {count}')
```

if you want this sorted alphabetically replace `d.items()` with `sorted(d.items())`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dsic = {'food': 3, 'games': 1, 'hi': 1}
```

you could try somthing like this maybe:

```
import json 
print(json.dumps(dsic, sort_keys=False, indent=4))
```

or this one:

```
for i,x in dsic.items():
    print(str(i)+': '  + str(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do your research before posting on stackoverflow.
For now, Hint is to use two loops. One for the list and one for printing the string.